# Return all relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to get all relationships in a graph without the nodes?

I'm trying

```
MATCH [r:MEMBER] 
RETURN r
```

But it gives me the error

```
Invalid input '[': expected whitespace, comment or a pattern (line 1, column 7 (offset: 6))
"MATCH [r:MEMBER] reTURN r"
       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Neo4j's relationships always have a direction, this is the fastest.

```
MATCH ()-[r:MEMBER]->()
RETURN r
```

Neo4j's browser will not display a graph, but just return the property maps of the relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match a relationship pattern:

```
MATCH ()-[r:MEMBER]-() 
RETURN r
```

Comment: thought I could just do something similar to `MATCH (n:Node)`